# Maximum file size can be read by logstash 2.4.0

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am trying to read a file and parse it by logstash and write my output in another file;

```
input_file -> logstash -> output_file
```

My parser works well, I have tested on a sample file which is about 1000 lines of a txt file.

The problem is, once I start the real test with a real file, which is between 200MB and 1GB, nothing happens. I have no output , neither with stdout nor a txt file.

The last thing that I questionned is the file size of the input file !

Can you please give me some ideas about the possiblities ? or how can I change the max file size for my input file ?

PS: I do my tests on Windows.

Edit: It works with Logstash 5.5.1 ! but what is the problem with V2.4.0 ?

Thansk a lot

Comment: You got any solution ?

Comment: I had to use V5.5.1. For the V2.4.0, I have not any explication !